# in what situation,gotoAndStop is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 3 frames, I don't show the whole code, it's too huge.and the main code is

```
gotoAndStop(2);
trace('frame:',currentFrame)
```

the output should be frame: 2

But in fact it's frame: 1, and objects in frame 2 cannot be loaded and become null
no compiler errors

When I delete some codes after it, the application sometimes operate right and stops at frame 2.
This shouldn't happen as any code after it should not involve the output
although I can solve this when I delete the first frame,but it's quite risky to keep developing.
Any ideas why this happen?

---

Before keep going,I should mention I actually have compiler errors due to null objects,but it's not the main point. 
And I have a class called host,the code `gotoAndStop` is also in the first place of constructor. 
I have put override function in host, and the output is

```
stopping at frame: 2 Called from: Error
    at host/gotoAndStop()
    at host()
frame: 1
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference
    at host()
```

Then I tried the method2 Creative Magic says,the result shows

```
stopping at frame: 2 Called from: Error
    at host/gotoAndStop()
    at host()
displaying frame: 1
frame: 1
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference
    at host()
displaying frame: 2
```

This quite confuses me what's happening in the frame,I wonder the cause is like you say old version of SDK,thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be either you've written buggy code or you use old Flash SDK.

In the first case you should check if you're calling gotoAndStop(), play() or gotoAndPlay() methods of your MovieClip. To do so you can edit the class of your MC:

- In Flash Professional in the library panel right-click on the MC
- Select "Edit Class"
- In your selected IDE add following function

  ```
  override public function gotoAndStop(frame:Object, scene:String = null):void
  {
      trace("stopping at frame:", frame, "Called from:", new Error().getStackTrace());
      super(this).gotoAndStop(frame, scene);
  }
  ```

It will trace when the gotoAndStop() method was called and who called it. It will let you see if the frame was set to frame by something else. I recommend you to override play() and gotoAndPlay() functions as well.

If you're intimidated by this code you could just add a trace() on each frame of your MC, since it's only 3 frames it shouldn't be too much work. Your trace could look something like that:

```
trace("displaying frame:", this.currentFrame);
```

The other possible cause could lie within the SDK you're using. I, myself had a strange bug when the loaded MC wouldn't listen to stop(), gotoAndStop() and other functions. The problem was solved by upgrading the SDK: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html
The explanation on how to replace the old SDK is there as well.